# Python input compared to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]

choice = input()

    if choice.isnumeric() and choice in nums:
        print("First")
   
    else:
        print("Second")
```

It prints out Second, can anyone explain why? I assume because it reads the number as a string since its `input()` rather than `int(input())`, and then it's `false` because list members are `int`, if that's the case, is it better to write the numbers in the list as strings, or is there another way to make it work?

Comment: Choice is a string. Try int(choice) in nums

Comment: Be careful with provided answers. You must handle the case where the input cannot be converted as a int. ```try/catch ValueError``` when casting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume because it reads the number as a string since its input() rather than int(input()), and then it's false because list members are int

That's right. But you can convert input value to int to make it work:

```
if choice.isnumeric() and int(choice) in nums:
    print("First")

else:
    print("Second")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can cast `choice` to `int` after `and`:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
choice = input()

if choice.isnumeric() and int(choice) in nums:
    print("First")
else:
    print("Second")
```